# USB flash drives appear and disappear instantly from Thunar (xfce)

Tags: xfce, chrome-os, chrome-book, thunar, thunar-volman

I have a HP Chromebook where i used crouton to install xfce on. Everything is working fine and expected. However when I whenever I plug up a flash drive (64bit formated with NTFS or 265MB formated with FAT32) I see the stick pop-up in the file explorer (Thunar) for a second and then immediately disappear before I could have time to click on it (similar like [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Crouton/comments/63v37o/usb_flash_drives_appear_and_disappear_instantly/)).

When I try the sticks in the default ChromeOS they work and are auto-mounted. So I think my issue is that ChromeOS auto-mount the stricks in the background while I´m using xfce.

If I try (inside xfce):

```
sudo mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/80F43972F3583C0B /home/user/64GBUSBStick
```

Then I get the error:

> Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
>   The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it
>   which could be identified for example by the help of the fuser command

However for the FAT32 stick its working ...

This might be (sorry if wrong, but I´m not a linux pro) due to the reason that when checking with

mount

that the devices can be both seen here:

/var/host/media/removable/64GB or /var/host/media/removable/265MB

However they where still not added to Thunar

Did anybody have a solution for that issue? My preferred one would be to keep both auto mount options up and running if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue after some days troubleshooting on my own: The problem is that Google Chrome auto mount the USB stick while xfce is only a kind of 2nd OS. So once Google Chrome stopped to auto mount the USB stick it will stay mounted in Thunar.